# OPEN MPI is not working for me

Tags: centos, openmpi, centos6.5

I have installed MPI and GCC seperatly using yum commands,
And now when I use following command:

```
mpic++ first.c -o first
```

it says:

```
bash: mpic++: command not found
```

**Can somebody please help me? I will be very thankful.**

*Background: I am using centos 6.5, and i am new on linux, however I have good understanding of terminal.*

Comment: You may forget to add the location of mpic++ in PATH variable.

Comment: thanks for your response,How can i get path to MPI? As when i use   which mpi, it says no mpi,

Comment: Try `mpiCC` instead of `mpic++`

Comment: Or `mpicpp`. All three alias to the same thing.

Comment: Did you install the run-time library **AND** the development package (`openmpi-dev`) or just the run-time library?

Comment: I installed it as: yum install openmpi and this command installed 1.5 version of openmpi,

Comment: `openmpi` is the Open MPI run-time package. You have to install `openmpi-dev` in order to get the header files and the compiler wrappers.

Comment: I have tried openmapi-dev still no luck.... After installing openmpi-dev i see there are files named mpicc, mpic++ etc in user/local/bin But I am not able to use them.. Kindly help me, I am struck with it

Answer (score 5):

Mpi environment is controlled by module in CentOS so you first have to load the mpi/openmpi-x86_64 module:

```
module load mpi/openmpi-x86_64
```

Comment: Yes I resolve this problems months ago, I should have posted a reply here so that it could be helpful for other. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: -bash: module: command not found

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Centos 7.5) the module command was not available, so I just needed to add the MPI executables to my path.

I found their location by looking at the output of this command:

```
rpmquery -l openmpi-devel | grep cc
```

And then added the following to my path:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin/
```

Answer (score 0):

See it: https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/csep524/13wi/mpi/mpi_setup.txt 
I also install mpi from **yum**, but **it can't help me**. I use:

download mpich

```
cd
wget http://www.mpich.org/static/tarballs/3.0.2/mpich-3.0.2.tar.gz
tar xzf mpich-3.0.2.tar.gz
```

build mpich and install in home (can also see mpich-3.0.2/README)

```
cd mpich-3.0.2
./configure --prefix=$HOME/mpich-install 2>&1 | tee c.txt
make 2>&1 | tee m.txt
make install 2>&1 | tee mi.txt
```

put mpi binaries (e.g. mpicc, mpirun) on your PATH
add the following line to your ~/.bashrc:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/mpich-install/bin
source ~/.bashrc
```

compile hello world:

```
mpicc helloworld.c -o helloworld
```

I get: cc: error: helloworld.c: No such file or director